# On lower complexity bounds for convex optimization algorithms

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, computational-complexity, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Consider the convex optimization problem $$\min_{x\in X} f(x),$$ where $X$ is convex compact and $f: \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ is convex. When studying the complexity of a certain algorithm $A$ for this problems, usually an upper bound of certain error $\epsilon_k$(ideally =0, being $k$ the iteration number) is determined. Hence we have a statement of the form $\epsilon_k\leq g(k)$, for some function $g$ such that $g(k)\to 0$ when $k\to\infty.$ Then, in order to analyze whether the method is efficient, they usually proceed to find a lower complexity bound, which is usually a statement of the type:  $$$$    $\textbf{Statement:}$ For any $1\leq k \leq n,$(hence $k$ is fixed) there exists a function $f$ and a compact convex set $X$ such that, when we apply method $A,$ we have $$\epsilon_k \geq h(k).$$ $$$$ My doubt lies in this Statement: How does that solves the problem of the lower complexity? It seems to me that the right statement should be $$$$ $\textbf{Statement Modified: }$  there exists a function $f$ and a compact convex set $X$ such that, when we apply method $A$ we have, $\textbf{for all }k\in \Bbb N, $ $$\epsilon_k \geq h(k).$$

EDIT: Due to a suggestion of Brian Borchers, I added a reference on which such STATEMENTS can be found.

In Nesterov's 'Introductory Lectures in Convex Optimization' you can find:

1. When analyzing smooth problems:
   [image]
2. When analyzing nonsmooth problems:

[image]

Comment: You haven't cited your source, so it's somewhat difficult to respond directly to this question.  However, the complexity lower bounds given in Nesterov's "Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization" aren't of the form you've described in your question.  You could clarify your question by citing your source.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I edited the question, as suggested. My reference is precisely Nesterov's ''Introductory Lectures in Convex Optimization''.

Comment: Another lower bound theorem in the book, Theorem 2.1.13, is stated in the stronger form.  Looking at the proof of theorem 2.1.7, it's not obvious to me how you could strengthen it.

Comment: @BrianBorchers thanks for the insight. I do not intend to strengthen the result, I just don't comprehend why does this solves the problem of the lower complexity. These bounds are just for the first iterations, but no information is given when $k$ is large. How should I interpret this examples in the question?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what your question is.  Theorem 2.1.7 as stated is enough to eliminate the possibility of an algorithm that gets a better solution in $k$ iterations- that's the main point of the lower bound.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks for taking the time of answering this. That is exactly my point. It eliminates the possibility of an algorithm that gets a better solution after $k$ iterations, BUT ONLY when $k\leq n.$ It says nothing when $k>n.$  So, in theory, is possible to have a method that, although it doesn't get a better solution after $k$ iterations, it actually improve this when $k\to \infty.$ And this is precisely the question. Theorem 2.1.13 seems right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65558/discussion-between-magnusseen-and-brian-borchers).